# passing variables between functions in same controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to pass variable between two functions in same controller?

Do I need to use **$this->session->set_flashdata** is this right way to go ?

```
function load() {
    $this->userhash = $this->uri->segment(3);
}

function save() {
    $query_customer = $this->Customers->get_customer($this->userhash);
}
```

sorry if this is a basic stuff, but I am still learning.

**I need to edit my question**

In Ivan link, that I also googled out

there is a code which goes something like this

```
function index() {
    $this->msg = 'data';
    $this->testme();
}

function testme() {
    echo $this->msg;
}
```

and its works, but I can not call **$this->testme()** directly in **index()**, so I can not load **save()** in **load()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Passing data between two functions in my controller class](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/58454/)

Comment: I also google this out, but here he is calling $this->index(); again in function, I can not do that. I just tried to use $this->session->set_flashdata and its working, but I am not sure is that a right way to do it.

Comment: You can use database or $_GET :)